Error 500 on POST https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/{scriptId}:run
I have a dummy function inside the Apps Script that I want to execute with Postman.
Apps Script simple dummy function
Every seems to be OK in my postman request, but I always recieve an error 500.
Here's the raw body:
{
  "function": "sendData",
  "parameters": [],  
  "devMode": false
}

The auth token and ScriptId are correct.
This is the response:
{
    "error": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Internal error encountered.",
        "status": "INTERNAL"
    }
}

It's driving me crazy. Any help on that?
I'm trying to execute a function that resides in the Apps Script from a Google Sheet.
I'm expecting to recieve an http code 200.

Add code as text, not as image.

Could you run sendData manually in the editor?

@TheMaster Yeah, I can run that function from the editor with no errors.

@Wicket Sorry, my bad.

Make sure you are following the steps to execute functions through the Apps Script API, the target script first needs to be deployed as API-executable.
